# Regular expression in Notepad++ for the replacing of one word per line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've been trying to replace (and translate) this text, and i don't know what formula I should Use for thousands of places that I need to translate to Spanish. OKay this is what i want to do, i want to use regular expressions on Notepadd++.

I give 4 variations, and in bold is what's supposed to go after the name of the place, in lower case and not to be confused with eg. **Agency Village** because that's its name.

> Missouri  5,988,927
>
> Adrian City **city**  1,677
>
> Advance **city**  1,347
>
> Affton **CDP**    20,307
>
> Agency Village **village**    684
>
> Airport Drive **village** 698

To

> | [[Adrian City (Misuri)|Adrian City]]
>   || **ciudad** || 1677
>
> |-
>
> | [[Advance (Misuri)|Advance]] ||
>   ciudad || 1347
>
> |-
>
> | [[Afton (Misuri)|Afton]] || CDP || 20307
>
> |-
>
> | [[Agency Village (Misuri)|Agency
>   Village]] || **villa** || 684
>
> |-
>
> | [[Airport Drive (Misuri)|Airport
>   Drive]] || villa || 698

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no way to get the Missouri from the first line into every following line with Notepad. In Notepad the regular expressions are limited to one row. There for you would need a scripting language like Perl.

Then you will need for every keyword a separate regular expression. For "city" it would be:

```
(.*)\scity\s(.*)
```

should be replaced with

```
| [[\1 (Misuri)|\1]] || ciudad || \2
```

The expression between the () are stored into variables and can be recalled with \1, \2, ... for the first, second, ... occurrence of brackets.

Take care if you have cases like

```
Adrian City village 1,677
```

you have to activate "Match case" and you need to rely on the upper/lower case distinction.

To remove the commas from the numbers:

```
(\d*),(\d*)
\1\2
```

Comment: +1, I second the statement about using a small script for this ... the only thing I don't get is how to distinguish the state from the settlement ...

Comment: to distinct between settlement and state: If every settlement has a keyword like city, village, CDP I could have a list of those. When the script finds a line with a string and a number but no keyword it has to be a state.